# "Square root" of a holomorphic automorphism

Tags: several-complex-variables

Suppose $F \in Aut(\mathbb{C}^n)$. Does there exist a $G \in Aut(\mathbb{C}^n)$ s.t. $G\circ G = F$?

Comment: It's certainly true for $n = 1$.

Comment: Yes it is, and for shears too.